# Spring boot embedded nettey server deadlock when calling the same service other endpoint

Tags: java, spring, spring-webflux, netty, spring-cloud-gateway

I am using Spring Cloud gateway, Spring boot webflux starter, and default embedded netty server.

I have created two routes

Route1: /api/v1/task
&
Route2: /api/v1/general

Route1: There are a few filters used by it that will update the request path and filter chain will continue and spring cloud gateway will call the proxy server, after receiving the response, custom filter will modify the response and update the headers, and then return the modified response.

Route2: There are different sets of filters that will do some work, call the localhost/api/v1/task using RestTemplate and do some modification on the response and return the modified response. The filter which is doing modification of RestTemplate response stops the filter chain and returns the response using `return exchange.mutate().response(res).build().getResponse().setComplete();`. As there is no proxy endpoint available I am stoping the chain.

Here, I am getting the response properly, but sometimes the service is getting stuck in some kind of deadlock.

I did some analysis and what I found is that, if the same `reactor-http-nio` thread is used by the inner API call(Using restTemplate to call Route1) which is used by route2 then the service is getting stuck and no other request will be served by the services. In order to confirm this behavior I updated the netty workerCount to 1 and saw that If I only call Route1 then services always returns the response. And if I use Route2 then the service will always get stuck and I need to restart the service to start using the other Routes.

In my application, I have 10+ routes and for the above-mentioned Route2, I have to call the other Routes with different parameters which will make 50+ API calls using localhost.

By looking at the behavior of the netty server, it looks like the first request will be served first, until the first request is not served, the 2nd request received on the same thread will get stuck and other threads will not pick it up. Due to this, I am facing a deadlock.

Could someone suggest a way to serve the 2nd request without waiting for the previous one to get clear? I looked into the thread dump and saw that RestTemplate.execute method was waiting for the response, even if other threads are free no other requests are getting accepted after the service gets stuck.

For now I have applied two things to stop the deadlock from occurring.

1. Increased the worker count to 80
2. Making the RestTemplate call in completable future and kept the timeout so that if timeout error is received I can fail the Route2 with 500 error.

--- Added after @DexterLegaspi  comment.

In my case, I am using XSLTs to construct the response for Route2. And my XSLT contains all the other API routes URLs using which I need to construct the response. To process XSLT I am using javax.xml TransformerFactory. To get the response from the API configured in XSLT I am using saxon library ExtensionFunctionDefinition(It allows to write custom functions in Java which can be called using the XSLT transformer). This function definition accepts the API path and returns the response of the API which needs to be a blocking function. If I use webClient blocking function then I am receiving a netty server `java.lang.IllegalStateException: block()/blockFirst()/blockLast() are blocking, which is not supported in thread reactor-http-nio-1` exception.

Comment: are you saying you are using RestTemplate in one of the filters?  you shouldn't use RestTemplate in a reactive stack; you should be using WebClient instead.

Comment: Yes,you are correct, I should be using WebClient but in my case, I can't. I have tried using WebClient too. But to fulfill my requirement, I need to make all the subsequent 50+ API calls in a synchronized manner. I must process the 1st API call response 1st then the 2nd and so on. As I am using the XSLTs to construct the final response, and the XSLT contains the other API references which I am processing using the ExtensionFunctionDefinition. I think now that there is only one solution to my problem that I process the XSLT 1st to get all the APIs,fetch all the resp then parse the XSLT w/ resp.

Comment: well, you can also compose Mono/Flux if result of one is dependent on another by using `Publisher::flatMap` or `Mono::zip` or `Flux::mergeWith` or `Flux::concat` so you can _still_ use `WebClient`.  I cannot further comment on this since i don't have full picture of your use case so we'll leave it at that :-)

Comment: Actually, we have similar deadlock with a regular SpringMVC. Even when making a sequence of requests via the same RestTemplate (meaning that second call goes after the first finishes request) in one thread, it randomly might hang up the whole application. This problem only occurs when we change all our underlying services' links to the WireMock instance (i.e. same host and port but endpoint is different). Also, there wasn't any problem even with WireMock mocks when we had RestTemplate bean being initialized via `new RestTemplate()` instead of `RestTemplateBuilder.build()`

Comment: Just for the update, recently we have resolved the issue, thanks to @dexter-legaspi for pointing me in the correct direction. Since I am new to the reactive APIs and Spring Gateway I was not following the best practices and I was not aware about most of the APIs in Mono object. I solved it by wrapping the entire service call in future objects and returning mono of void to the GatewayHandler which frees the netty server thread and allows other API calls on the same thread. Now it works even with a single Netty server thread. I will share the code soon as an answer to this question.